# How to send mulitple arrays as json from android and read it in php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I dont want to send simple key value pairs to the php script. 
i want to do something like this :

```
[{"PD_ID":"____","PD_NAME":"____","PD_UNIT":"___","PD_PRICE":"___","PD_CATEGORY":"___",
"PD_DESCRIPTION":"_____"}]
```

But then there will be multiple such json arrays like this which i will retrieve from list view which will contain these multiple products. 
So in simple words i want to know how to send a bundle of Json arrays to php script. 
I want to store this Json array directly into MySQL column.
I also want to know how do i store a json array directly into a single column.

Comment: You are asking a lot of stuff! But look at the php function json_encode/json_decode.

Comment: You would put two or more Json Arrays into an encompassing JsonArray or JSONObject

Comment: @Blundell : I have not quite understood what you have said. 
could you please give a small example or a link. 
thank you.

Comment: use a different parameter for each (a0,a1,a2..) or [[], [], []..]

Comment: like miki said, give each an Unique ID and let the php script loop through each ID and its data, then do whatever you want with it and insert it to you MySQL DB

Comment: Take a look here http://www.json.org/ it explains how you can have Arrays within Arrays

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this link for creating a json](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html)

create a json with this and you can send the file over http and set the type of it as json 
check mime header specs for setting the header as json

SERVER SIDE

php script has a json library as well so extract the req. params and save the array in the same column